# Bluetooth: no adapters found

Tags: wireless, bluetooth

I'm using a Bluetooth keyboard and all was working fine, until today. It stopped working. My Bluetooth applet says 'No adapters found'. I've got a Asus UX303LA.

When using `sudo service bluetooth status`, this is the output:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since wo 2015-08-12 10:55:09 CEST; 13min ago
 Main PID: 2792 (bluetoothd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─2792 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd -n

aug 12 10:55:09 stephan-UX303LA bluetoothd[2792]: bluetoothd[2792]: DIS cannot start: GATT is disabled
aug 12 10:55:09 stephan-UX303LA bluetoothd[2792]: bluetoothd[2792]: Failed to init deviceinfo plugin
aug 12 10:55:09 stephan-UX303LA bluetoothd[2792]: bluetoothd[2792]: Failed to init proximity plugin
aug 12 10:55:09 stephan-UX303LA bluetoothd[2792]: bluetoothd[2792]: Failed to init time plugin
aug 12 10:55:09 stephan-UX303LA bluetoothd[2792]: bluetoothd[2792]: Failed to init alert plugin
aug 12 10:55:09 stephan-UX303LA bluetoothd[2792]: bluetoothd[2792]: Failed to init thermometer plugin
aug 12 10:55:09 stephan-UX303LA bluetoothd[2792]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
aug 12 10:55:09 stephan-UX303LA bluetoothd[2792]: Bluetooth Management interface initialized
aug 12 10:55:09 stephan-UX303LA bluetoothd[2792]: bluetoothd[2792]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
aug 12 10:55:09 stephan-UX303LA bluetoothd[2792]: bluetoothd[2792]: Bluetooth Management interface initialized
```

`hcitool dev` gives no devices.

How can I figure out what's going wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question and add output of `lsusb; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: how did you get the output for `bluetooth.service`?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem wiht same errors after upgrade on a ThinkPad X220. I've solved the problem installing bluez-utils:

```
sudo apt install bluez-utils
```

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of "no adapters found" by simply restarting bluetooth:
`sudo service bluetooth restart`.